# What is the product formed after nitrosation of ketones (HNO2 + ketone)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

[image]

On C-nitrosation of ketones we get oximes. After this, the oxime formed is hydrolyzed ($\ce{H3O+}$ is added). What will be formed in the end? Does it follow Beckmann rearrangement or what?

Comment: Two answers here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86061/what-is-the-mechanism-of-the-reaction-between-hexane-2-5-dione-and-nitrous-acid/86090#86090

Answer (score 3):

Hydrolysis of the ketone oxime gives the 1,2-diketone as reported in this [Synlett reference](https://www.thieme-connect.com/products/ejournals/html/10.1055/s-2004-832815):

> Treatment of alpha-methylene ketones with excess sodium nitrite and
>   aqueous HCl in THF at reduced temperature provieds an effective tool
>   for the preparation of a variety of 1,2-diketones